# Declaring pointer to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When I declare:

```
struct str_node{
    int data;
    struct str_node *next;
}node;

node *head = NULL;
```

Is it something like:

```
head = NULL;
```

or

```
*head = NULL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every declaration is in the following format:

```
Type varName = initializer;
```

In your case

```
node *     head          =   NULL;
 ^          ^                 ^
| Type |  | varName | = | initializer |;
```

So, `head` is a variable which type is `node *` (pointer to `node`). The variable is `head` which value is initialized to `NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to expand Roberto's answer.

This

`node *head = NULL;`

will NOT compile because `node` is not a type, it's actually a variable `struct str_node` named `node`.
If you want to define a type, use the `typedef` specifier, like so

```
typedef struct str_node{
    int data;
    struct str_node *next;
}node;

node *head = NULL;
```

Comment: Yes sorry  I didn't copy the code right, but I wrote it like you did.

Answer (score 2):

Define a pointer **and** set its value to `NULL`:

```
int *head = NULL;
// conceptual    memory address    value
// head          0xABCD0000        0          
// that is;
// head is pointing to nowhere
```

Define a pointer **then** set its value to `NULL`:

```
int *head;
head = NULL;
// conceptual    memory address    value
// head          0xABCD0000        0          
// that is;
// head is pointing to nowhere
```

Define a pointer **then** set the memory address it's pointing at to `0`:

```
int *head;
head = 0xDCBA0000; // or a "malloc" function 
*head = 0;
// conceptual    memory address    value
// head          0xABCD0000        0xDCBA0000          
// ...
// *head         0xDCBA0000        0
// that is;
// head is pointing to 0xDCBA0000
// and the value of the memory it's pointing at is set to zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!
It's like
`head = NULL;`